# passing [value%] to parameter in crystal report

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

dear all I tried to add query into crystal report command
the query is

```
Declare @FromDate Datetime
Declare @ToDate Datetime
Declare @Whse nvarchar(10)
 select @FromDate = min(S0.Docdate) from dbo.OINM S0 where S0.Docdate >={?@FromDate}
 select @ToDate = max(S1.Docdate) from dbo.OINM s1 where S1.Docdate <={?@ToDate}
select @Whse = Max(s2.Warehouse) from dbo.OINM S2 Where S2.Warehouse ='[%2]'
Select @Whse as 'Warehouse', a.Itemcode, max(a.Dscription) as ItemName,
sum(a.OpeningBalance) as OpeningBalance, sum(a.INq) as 'IN', sum(a.OUT) as OUT,
...
```

the original query is

```
...select @FromDate = min(S0.Docdate) from dbo.OINM S0 where S0.Docdate >='[%0]'
 select @ToDate = max(S1.Docdate) from dbo.OINM s1 where S1.Docdate <='[%1]'
select @Whse = Max(s2.Warehouse) from dbo.OINM S2 Where S2.Warehouse ='[%2]'
```

I changed `'[%0]` to be `>={?@FromDate}` (parameter) and it is work fine the same for `'[%1]'` now I can't change `'[%2]'` the only thing work with me is to change it into `{?@Whse}` but this give me wrong data in the report

regards

Comment: What exactly is the error you are getting and when do you receive it? Also, have you already created the Whse parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change it to

**select @Whse = Max(s2.Warehouse) from dbo.OINM S2 Where S2.Warehouse ={?@select*from OWHS}**

its work fine but for if you select more than one warehouse you will have error

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear whats are you trying to obtain from the where clause, but if you're trying to obtain those warehouse with the text: 2% you can try like??

Try these:

```
select @Whse = Max(s2.Warehouse) from dbo.OINM S2 Where S2.Warehouse Like '%2'
```